# How to omit Get only properties in servicestack json serializer?

Tags: json, properties, servicestack

I have an object which I am de-serializing using `ToJson<>()` method from ServiceStack.Text namespace.

How to omit all the `GET` only propeties during serialization? Is there any attribute like `[Ignore]` or something that I can decorate my properties with, so that they can be omitted?

Thanks

Answer (score 60, accepted):

[ServiceStack's Text serializers](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) follows .NET's DataContract serializer behavior, which means you can ignore data members by using the opt-out `[IgnoreDataMember]` attribute

```
public class Poco 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public string IsIgnored { get; set; }
}
```

An opt-in alternative is to decorate every property you want serialized with `[DataMember]`. The remaining properties aren't serialized, e.g:

```
[DataContract]
public class Poco 
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string IsIgnored { get; set; }
}
```

Finally there's also a non-intrusive option that doesn't require attributes, e.g:

```
JsConfig<Poco>.ExcludePropertyNames = new [] { "IsIgnored" };
```

### Dynamically specifying properties that should be serialized

ServiceStack's Serializers also supports dynamically controlling serialization by providing conventionally named `ShouldSerialize({PropertyName})` methods to indicate whether a property should be serialized or not, e.g:

```
public class Poco 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string IsIgnored { get; set; }

    public bool? ShouldSerialize(string fieldName)
    {
        return fieldName == "IsIgnored";
    }
}
```

More examples in [ConditionalSerializationTests.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Text.Tests/JsonTests/ConditionalSerializationTests.cs)

Comment: Option 1 looks best for my scenario. Thanks for quick help.

Comment: I must say that the third option is amazing! :-) When you have to deal with code you can't change that's the way to go. I also find it enormously elegant.

Comment: Yeah good detail provided. And 3rd option is cool as it provides runtime control.

Comment: [IgnoreDataMember] does not work with OrmLite, or did I miss something?

Comment: @ErwinMayer Yeah it only applies to serialization. Use ServiceStack.DataAnnotations's [Ignore] attribute for OrmLite Data Models.

Comment: @mythz: Would be very helpful to support something like this: JsConfig.IgnoreReadOnlyProperties = true;

Comment: Sorry if this is common knowledge now, but I did discover that you can do this:

JsConfig.IgnoreAttributesNamed = new[] { nameof(IgnoreAttribute) };

and that will let you use the same Ignore attribute you use for ORMLite.

Comment: `ShouldSerialize()` doesn't receive the field name, it receives the JSON name, so if you use `DataMember` with `Name`, you have to supply that and keep track in both places. It would really be nice to have an attribute to specify incoming only or outgoing only.

Answer (score 0):

For nullable members, you also have the ability to set it to null before serializing.

This is particularly useful if you want to create a single view/api model that is re-used for several API calls. The service can touch it up before setting it on the response object.

Example:

```
    public SignInPostResponse Post(SignInPost request)
    {
        UserAuthentication auth = _userService.SignIn(request.Domain, true, request.Username, request.Password);

        // Map domain model ojbect to API model object. These classes are used with several API calls.
        var webAuth = Map<WebUserAuthentication>(auth);

        // Exmaple: Clear a property that I don't want to return for this API call... for whatever reason.
        webAuth.AuthenticationType = null;

        var response = new SignInPostResponse { Results = webAuth };
        return response;
    }
```

I do wish there was a way to dynamically control the serialization of all members (including non-nullable) on a per endpoint fashion.