# Does ServiceStack ormlite has the concept of transient attribute?

Tags: c#, orm, mono, stack-overflow, ormlite-servicestack

I am newbie to servicestack and ormlite.

I am trying to have fields to be used for displaying / serialization purposes not for persistance purposes. I tried [ignoredatamemebr] but this ignore both persistance and serialization.  I want to do something similar to [notmapped] in entity framework and like @transient in hibernate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `[Ignore]` attribute to ignore properties from being persisted in OrmLite.

Whilst here are different ways to [ignore properties during serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14859968/85785).

Comment: Sorry of being late due to work load at my day job. Thanks for your fast response. Unfortunately, I tested all possibilities in the provided link but it did not work as I expected. I wanted to reuse the DTO that I used for creating table with extra information (description fields for foreign keys (Ids)) to be returned  for view purposes which is similar to ViewModel in MVC applications. I can create viewModel instead of reuse the DTO but I am in learning process and I want to discover opportunities to reuse code.

Comment: @Shaheen The recommendation is [not to re-use DTO's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15369736/85785) but as stated, `[Ignore]` is how to get OrmLite to ignore properties, just as your question asked.

Comment: thanks for great references. Your help is highly appreciated.