# Serializing CustomUserSession in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-text

We're trying to use Redis ICacheClient with a CustomUserSession, but our custom properties are not stored. The problem seems to be in the json created by serializer.

Here a test:

```
public class CustomUserSession : AuthUserSession
{
    public string Test { get; set; }
}

[TestFixture]
public class UserSessionJsonTest
{
    private CustomUserSession session;

    [Test]
    public void CanSerializeToJson()
    {
        session = new CustomUserSession()
        {
            UserName = "Ivan",
            Address = "Address1",
            Test = "123"
        };
        JsConfig<CustomUserSession>.ExcludeTypeInfo = false;
        JsConfig<CustomUserSession>.IncludeTypeInfo = true;
        var json = JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(session);
        Debug.WriteLine(json);
        Assert.That(json.Contains("123"));
    }
}
```

Test is not  serialized at all, any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In v4, attributes are inherited and because [AuthUserSession](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/AuthUserSession.cs) is a DataContract, where the [serialization is opt-in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14859968/85785), you need to mark each property you want to serialize with `[DataMember]`, e.g:

```
public class TestUserSession : AuthUserSession
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Test { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thx! ServiceStack support is amazing!