# Different serialization strategy for two different serializers

Tags: c#, json, wcf, serialization, servicestack

I'm using WCF & Redis as caching layer, but unfortunately both WCF and the driver I used, are looking for the `DataContractAttribute` & `DataMemberAttribute` - and I want to  hide some fields from WCF (sensitive information) but they should get serialized down to Redis (Uses StackService.JsonSerializer).

I want to achieve this without writing 2 different classes and want to switch between them at runtime, but I'm not sure if it's possible or not.

Thanks!

Comment: if there's no distinguishing feature, you cannot distinguish. Disregarding technical/budgetary feasibility, you'd have to create a new attribute to be able to distinguish. Then wrap/decorate one of the serializers to look at the other attribute.

Comment: See this answer on how to [ignore fields with ServiceStack JSON Serializer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14859968/85785).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, how StackService.JsonSerialzer works.

But for DataContract you can remove DataMember attribute from sensitive fields and they will not be serialized

Comment: On classes marked with DataContract, StackService.JsonSerialzer doesn't serialize any member not marked with DataMember