# Ignore properties if not authenticated or some authentication rule

Tags: web-services, servicestack

I have a service in ServiceStack with a DTO that returns multiple properties, but some can only be returned if the person is authenticated, or if some rule.

How can I do this?

The attribute can only be used in class or method and not a property.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to [ignore properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14859968/85785) in serialization, using [Conditional Serialization](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Text.Tests/JsonTests/ConditionalSerializationTests.cs) is likely the most useful here.

But I'd personally avoid using bespoke serialization features and just use **vanilla C#** to set the properties you don't want to return to `null`, either within your service or in one of the [Custom Response Filters and Hooks](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Order-of-Operations).

Comment: Would for example create an attribute, permission and GlobalResponseFilters, change the DTO to return the correct object? 

Because it would be difficult for any property to create a validation method.

Tranks.