# ServiceStack AutoQuery partial response returns unwanted GUID, int etc

Tags: c#, servicestack

I am working on ServiceStack's partial response on AutoQuery, code snippets as follow:

```
public class SalesOrderServices : MyService
    {
        Utilities.RequestUtilities utilities = new Utilities.RequestUtilities();

        public object Any(SalesOrdersGet request)
        {
            String qString = GetSelectString(base.Request);

            var q = AutoQuery.CreateQuery(request, Request.GetRequestParams());

            if (!qString.IsNullOrEmpty())
            {
                q.Select(qString);
            }

            return AutoQuery.Execute(request, q);
        }
```

which inherits MyService

```
namespace WombatWS.ServiceInterface.Sales
{
    public class MyService : Service
    {
        public IAutoQuery AutoQuery { get; set; }

        public String GetSelectString(IRequest request)
        {
            String qString = "";

            if (!request.QueryString["fields"].IsNullOrEmpty())
            {
                String sFields = request.QueryString["fields"].ToString();
                String[] properties = sFields.Split(',');

                foreach (String s in properties)
                {
                    if (!s.Equals(properties.Last().ToString()))
                    {
                        qString += s + ",";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        qString += s;
                    }
                }
            }
            return qString;
        }
    }
}
```

I noticed besides the interesting fields I put into `?field={field1},{field2}...`, unwanted DateTime would be returned as what it is, as well as all the int, GUID types will be also returned as 0, 0000-000000000-0000-00000 something. How to get rid of them? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Guid` (like an integer) is a value type and every value type must have a value, the default value type of a Guid is `new Guid()` which is `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`.

If you don't want value types to emit values then you need to use a nullable `Guid?`. Or you could configure ServiceStack Text serializers not to emit value types with default values with:

```
JsConifg.ExcludeDefaultValues = true;
```

Another option is to customize the serialization by [implementing ShouldSerialize to ignore fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14859968/85785) with default values, e.g:

```
class Poco
{
     public Guid Guid { get; set; }

    public bool? ShouldSerialize(string fieldName)
    {
        return fieldName == "Guid" ? Guid != default(Guid) : true;
    }
}
```