# Servicestack - architecture & reusing POCOs for everything

Tags: architecture, servicestack, separation-of-concerns

I refer to [ServiceStack documentation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Advantages-of-message-based-web-services#code-first-pocos) reg use of POCOs:

> Since it promotes clean, re-usable code, ServiceStack has always encouraged the use of **code-first POCO's for just about everything.**
>
> **i.e. the same POCO can be used:**
> In Request and Response DTO's (on client and server)
> In JSON, JSV and CSV Text Serializers
> As the data model in OrmLite, db4o and NHibernate
> As the entities stored in Redis
> As blobs stored in Caches and Sessions
> Dropped and executed in MQ's services"

I love servicestack & how easy it is to write web services with it. I am trying to understand how best to setup my project & not run into any issues down the road.

Specifically, I am battling with the architectural idea of returning a response object that is also a data model (as suggested by SS). The idea of seperation of concerns is too strongly ingrained within me. Won't one run into problems down the road if you use the same POCOs for everything. Is it not "safer" to e.g return eg view objects instead?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

### Software's biggest enemy

Firstly I want to iterate that 
[Complexity and Large Code bases](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2007/12/codes-worst-enemy.html)
is the single worst enemy of software development, and that along with meeting the project requirements 
(i.e. deriving value from our software), managing complexity and maintaining a minimal and low friction, 
evolvable code-base should be at the forefront of our minds as we're continually enhancing our software with 
new features and requirements. Any guidelines, rules or processes we add to increase software quality should 
be directly focused on managing its essential complexity. One of the best things we can do to reduce complexity 
is to reduce code-base size, i.e. DRYing repeatable code and eliminating any unnecessary abstractions, 
indirection, concepts, types and friction that isn't absolutely essential to the software's function.

In this light, [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) is one of the best principles 
to follow to ensure a simple and lean code-base by focusing on what's essential to delivering value.

#### Avoid blanket rules

I avoid "blanket rules" which I consider one of the primary causes of unnecessary complexity in Software, 
where it's often liberally and thoughtlessly applied, infecting a code-base without justification.
Every time you impose an artificial limitation, you're creating friction and inertia to develop within its bounds 
in order to satisfy it, which is why any rule you enforce should be thoughtfully and carefully applied 
and limited to places where it adds value.

#### Be wary of invalid Rules and Patterns

Even Software Design Patterns are in many cases 
[programming language deficiencies](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AreDesignPatternsMissingLanguageFeatures), where 
what's a useful in one language is unnecessary and 
more elegantly solved in more expressive and powerful languages. Likewise with "rules", what's a 
cautionary guideline in one domain may not be applicable in others. Therefore what's more important than 
"the rule" itself, is the value it actually provides and what concrete side-effect it's trying to prevent. 
Once we understand its true value, we can optimize to derive maximum value from it and together with YAGNI, 
know when to selectively apply it.

### The Simple POCO Life

As you've noticed ServiceStack achieves a lot of its simplicity and reuse by being able to reuse the same 
POCOs indiscriminately anywhere to interface and freely communicate between its different libraries and components. 
This enables maximum value and reuse of your Models and reduces the friction in mapping between different domains 
which typically require having purpose-specific types, each with its own unique configuration limiting its 
applicability and potential re-use.

#### Heavy ORM models are poor DTOs

Not reusing data models as DTOs applies to Heavy ORM's which encourage Data Models with cyclical dependencies 
and proxied objects with tight coupling and embedded logic that can trigger unintended N+1 data access, making 
these models poor candidates for use as DTOs and why you should always copy them into purpose-specific
DTOs that your Services can return so they're serializable without issue.

#### Clean POCOs

The complex Data Models stored in 
[OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite) or 
[Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis) doesn't suffer from any of these issues which are able to use 
clean, disconnected POCOs. They're loosely-coupled, where only the "Shape" of the POCO is significant, i.e. 
moving projects and changing namespaces won't impact serialization, how it's stored in RDBMS tables, 
Redis data structures, Caching providers, etc. 
You're also not coupled to specific types, you can use a different type to insert data in OrmLite than what you
use to read from it, nor does it need to be the "exact Shape", as OrmLite can populate a DTO with only a
subset of the fields available in the underlying table. There's also no distinction between Table, View or 
Stored procedure, OrmLite will happily map any result-set into any matching fields on the specified POCO, 
ignoring others.

Effectively this means POCOs in ServiceStack are extremely resilient and interoperable, so you can happily
re-use the same DTOs in OrmLite and vice-versa without issue. If the DTO and Data models only deviate slightly, 
you can [hide them from being serialized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14859968/85785) or stored in OrmLite with 
the attributes below:

```
public class Poco
{
    [Ignore]
    public int IgnoreInOrmLite { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public int IgnoreInSerialization { get; set; }
}
```

Otherwise when you need to separate them, e.g. more fields were added to the RDBMS table than you want to 
return, the DTO includes additional fields populated from alternative sources, or you just want your Services
to project them differently. At that point (YAGNI) you can take a copy of the DTO and add it to your Services 
Implementation so they can grow separately, unimpeded by their different concerns. 
You can then effortlessly convert between them using
[ServiceStack's built-in Auto Mapping](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-mapping), e.g:

```
var dto = dbPoco.ConvertTo<Poco>();
```

> The built-in Auto Mapping is also very tolerant and can co-erce properties with different types,
>    e.g. to/from strings, different collection types, etc.

### Data Transfer Objects - DTOs

So if you're using clean, serializable POCOs without external dependencies (e.g. from OrmLite, Redis or alt 
ServiceStack sources) you can happily re-use them as DTOs and freely refactor them out into different models 
as-and-when you need to. But when you are re-using Data Models as DTOs they should still be maintained in the 
**ServiceModel** project (aka DTO .dll) which should contain **all the types** that your Service returns.
DTOs should be logic and dependency-free so the only dependency the ServiceModel project references is the 
impl-free  `ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll` which as it's a PCL .dll, can be freely referenced from all 
[.NET Mobile and Desktop platforms](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HelloMobile).

You want to ensure all types your Services return are in the DTO .dll since this, along with the base url of 
where your Services are hosted is **all that's required** for your Service Consumers to know in order to 
consume your Services. Which they can use with any of the 
[.NET Service Clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client)
to get an end-to-end Typed API without code-gen, tooling or any other artificial machinery. 
If clients prefer source code instead, they can use 
[Add ServiceStack Reference](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Add-ServiceStack-Reference) 
to access the Servers typed DTOs in their preferred platform and language of choice.

### Services

Services are the ultimate form of encapsulating complexity and offers the highest level of software reuse.
They package its capabilities and makes them available remotely to your consumers with never any more 
complexity than the cost of a Service call.

[image: DTO Interface vs Service Implementation]

The DTOs are what defines your Services contract, keeping them isolated from any Server implementation is 
how your Service is able to encapsulate its capabilities (which can be of unbounded complexity) and make them
available behind a remote facade. It separates what your Service provides from the complexity in how it 
realizes it. It defines the API for your Service and tells Service Consumers the minimum info they need to know 
to discover what functionality your Services provide and how to consume them 
(maintaining a similar role to Header files in C/C++ source code). 
Well-defined Service contracts decoupled from implementation, enforces interoperability ensuring that 
your Services don't mandate specific client implementations, ensuring they can be consumed by any HTTP 
Client on any platform. DTOs also define the shape and structure of your Services wire-format, ensuring they can
be cleanly deserialized into native data structures, eliminating the effort in manually parsing Service Responses.

#### Parallel Client development

Since they capture the entire contract it also enables clients to develop their applications before the 
Services are implemented as they're able to bind their application to its concrete DTO models and can easily 
mock their Service client to return test data until the back-end Services are implemented.

As far as rules go, ensuring a well-defined Service Contract (DTOs) decoupled from its implementation 
goes to very essence of what a Service is and the value it provides.

#### Request and Response DTOs

As for which DTOs make good candidates for re-use as Data Models, you don't want to use **Request DTOs**
for anything other than defining your external Services API which is typically a **Verb** that's ideally 
[grouped by Call Semantics and Response Types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15941229/85785), e.g:

```
public class SearchProducts : IReturn<SearchProductsResponse> 
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public decimal? PriceGreaterThan { get; set; }
}
```

Your RDBMS tables are normally entities defined as **Nouns**, i.e. what your Service returns:

```
public class SearchProductsResponse
{
    public List<Product> Results { get; set; }        
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Even the containing **Response DTO** which defines what your Service returns isn't a good candidate for re-use 
as a Data Model. I'd typically use discrete DTOs for Service Responses as it allows freely extending existing 
Services to return extra data or metadata without breaking existing clients.

Other than the Request and Response DTOs, all other the **Types** that your Service returns would be 
candidates for re-use as Data Models, which I frequently do, keeping them in the **ServiceModel** project 
for the reasons above.

Comment: what a great answer. I'll reread & refer to this a number of times.

Comment: Could you share your experience, what rules are abused heavily dealing damage to code base?

Comment: @FireAlkazar Every pattern/process can be abused to the detriment of code-bases. Many OOP devs start with [Object Happiness](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/03/18/92422.aspx) and believe more abstract and indirection added is an improvement due to some hypothetical attribute that's never realized. Adding interfaces/mocking Models or creating interfaces for types with only 1 impl shows thoughtless use of interfaces, decoupling pure logic into injected dependencies (that doesn't require deps) is an over use of DI/IOC's. Inheritance for code reuse is abuse of OOP constructs etc.

Comment: @mythz: In the sample what's the point of `IgnoreInSerialization` property not being serialiazed but populated from OrmLite only? Are the consumers of the typed service supposed to read some kind of documentation for this DTO to realize that a property left over from the data-access layer is to be ignored? The only case I'm using the `IgnoreDataMember` attrib is for convenience properties e.g. `StockStatus` to `StockStatusText` "explains" the first one, so the latter is impl as a simple lookup directly in the DTO and carries no separate data.

Comment: "Even the containing Response DTO which defines what your Service returns isn't a good candidate for re-use as a Data Model." - But, Results property of Response DTO can be used as Data Model? Or I'm missing something?

Comment: @Tenek Response DTOs (when not returning naked Types or collections) is typically specific to a single Service so they're not reusable, but the DTO Types they contain are reusable.

Comment: Thanks I think I see what you mean. Sounds like having generic response DTO would be a good mitigation of this concern: IDtoResponseEnvelop<List<Product>>?

Comment: @Tenek A generic Response DTO defeats the purpose of even having one where you can evolve each service contract independently without breaking existing clients, see [docs on Message-based APIs](http://docs.servicestack.net/design-message-based-apis#returning-coarse-grained-response-dtos) for more info. The goal shouldn't be to reuse Response DTOs whose purpose is to define the Services Response, you can reuse all other DTO Types.

Comment: Gotcha. I was thinking that wrapping "naked" dtos from service into generic dto response envelope be a good way to provide an operation status together with the results and eliminate need to have a concrete Response dtos implementation per service. but I think I already asked too much questions. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: I first used ServiceStack years ago and stumbled upon this excellent response in regards to a type of unneeded complexity. Now I am a project that demands WebAPI, and I find myself in the same delimma of separate response and request objects just to abstract the domain (database) entities. For now I'm going to stick to POCO reuese.

Comment: "Heavy ORM models are poor DTOs" I'd give you 5 upvotes for this statement alone.  I can't tell you how many holy war discussions I've had with passing heavy ORM models "over the wire"........and because "its faster development time".   Gaaaaaaaaaa.