# How to document models & services which are in a separate project

Tags: servicestack, swagger

I'm looking to demonstrate ServiceStack to my team, and as part of the demo I want to create some documentation. The UseCases.SwaggerHelloWorld runs fine, but my project (which has 1 functioning service) returns an empty swagger page. When I visit /resources it returns:

```js
{
  "swaggerVersion":"1.2",
  "apis":[],
  "apiVersion":"1.0",
  "basePath":"http://localhost:29672",
  "info":{"title":"Reports.Api"}
}
```

I then copied the Hello* service and models into my API project (in the same assembly as the host) and this worked. I then moved the service and models out into separate projects and the docs disappeared again.

So my question is, how can you document APIs when the models are in a separate DLL? The project structure is the same as recommended when you create a solution using the servicestack solution template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AppHost constructor tells ServiceStack which assemblies it should scan to locate, register and auto-wire your Services, e.g:

```
public class AppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public AppHost() : base("Hello App", typeof(HelloService).Assembly) {}
}
```

It supports specifying multiple Assemblies if your Services are maintained in different projects, e.g:

```
public class AppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public AppHost() : base("Hello App", 
        typeof(HelloService).Assembly, typeof(OtherService).Assembly) {}
}
```

The [Modularizing Services docs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Modularizing-services) has more info.

The DTO's used by the Service can be in a different project, you just need to specify which assemblies the Services are in. Although it's recommended the DTO's are maintained in a [separate dep-free project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32940275/85785) which is the recommended [Physical Project Structure](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Physical-project-structure) that's contained in each [ServiceStackVS VS.NET Project Template](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStackVS).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Useful stuff, but I probably didn't make it clear. I have registered and auto-wired services as above, and configured AppHost to reference the other assembly. All is working and metadata returns these services / routes etc. It is just swagger doesn't work. The JSON returned at /resources returns empty. If I move all code into the host project, swagger works fine, as per the sample app. So how do I tell swagger where to find the services / models when they live in a different assembly and/or namespace?

Comment: ...in other words how do I influence how /resources is being built, at it is not working correctly for me.

Comment: @NeilDobson I've done what you said with the SwaggerHelloWorld project [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.UseCases/commit/de14dcf430f454f1dfdf556487b9886817d51a31) and split Services across into a [new project](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.UseCases/commit/f9e58cea0e52218847997a17dc7a39b5180176bd), Swagger still works whether I reference 1 or both assemblies. Can you submit a pull-request that exhibits the issue you're seeing?

Comment: Thanks @mythz After some tinkering I found the problem. I have a route of [Route("/{AgencyKey}/carerCriminalCheck/", Summary = "Carer Criminal Check Report")]. This is a multi-tenancy system and I wanted to demonstrate all routes are prefixed with key. Later will change this so key is part of auth. Anyway once I changed route to /carerCriminalCheck/{AgencyKey} the service appeared in swagger. So I guess something is a bit picky about the routing. Anyway, all good now. Thanks.

Comment: @NeilDobson yeah only the [Fallback Route](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing#fallback-route) can start with a non-literal route.