# ORMLite SQL Server Update

Tags: servicestack

I have a table called PODetail with a primary Key of POno and ItemCode and I have the following:

```
[Route("/podetail/{POno}/{ItemCode}")]
    public class UpdatePODetail : IReturn<PODetail> {
        public string POno { get; set; }
        public string ItemCode  { get; set; }

        public int ?     QtyPend { get; set; }
        public decimal ? NewPrice { get; set; }
        public bool ? BackOrder { get; set; }
        public string  ActionCode { get; set; }
        public bool ? OpenOrder { get; set; }
    }

 public class PODetailService : Service {
    public object Any(UpdatePODetail request) {
        var podetail =  Db.SingleFmt<PODetail>("ItemCode = {0} AND POno = {1}", request.ItemCode, request.POno);
        // var cap = new CaptureSqlFilter();
        try {
            Db.Update(podetail);
        } catch {
            // var sql = string.Join(";\n\n", cap.SqlStatements.ToArray());
        }
        :
        :

        try {
            Db.Update(podetail);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            string error = ex.Message;
        }
        return podetail;
    }
}
```

I added the Db.Update call at the top just to check to see if there was some issue changing a column, but I get

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'aaaaaPoDetail_PK'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.PODetail'.

So then I added the cap = line to see the SQL code which returns

```
UPDATE "PODetail" SET "NewItemCode"=@NewItemCode, "POno"=@POno, "Vendor"=@Vendor, "ActionCode"=@ActionCode, "Price"=@Price, "NewPrice"=@NewPrice, "CostPrice"=@CostPrice, "QtyOrd"=@QtyOrd, "QtyRcv"=@QtyRcv, "QtySPO"=@QtySPO, "QtyPend"=@QtyPend, "BackOrder"=@BackOrder, "OpenOrder"=@OpenOrder, "OrderDate"=@OrderDate, "InvoiceNo"=@InvoiceNo, "InvoiceVendor"=@InvoiceVendor, "InvoiceDate"=@InvoiceDate, "InvoiceDiscount"=@InvoiceDiscount, "QtyCancel"=@QtyCancel, "Qtylabels"=@Qtylabels, "REOVendor"=@REOVendor, "CurrentRcvQty"=@CurrentRcvQty, "SOPickQty"=@SOPickQty, "SOItem"=@SOItem, "QtyOther"=@QtyOther, "BackOrderCode"=@BackOrderCode WHERE "ItemCode"=@ItemCode
```

And then it runs fine uncommented -- no exceptions .. if I remove it it gets the Primary Key error

What is the deal -- why do I need that CaptureSqlFilter call -- or what I do I need to change so that it knows both PoNo and ItemCode are primary Keys or the update needs to say WHERE "ItemCode"=@ItemCode AND "POno"=@PONo?  It almost seems as if it is trying to do an INSERT vs an UPDATE without the CaptureSqlFilter

### Update 1

The documentation said :

> Limitations For simplicity, and to be able to have the same POCO class
>   persisted in db4o, memcached, redis or on the filesystem (i.e.
>   providers included in ServiceStack), each model must have a single
>   primary key, by convention OrmLite expects it to be Id although you
>   use [Alias("DbFieldName")] attribute it map it to a column with a
>   different name or use the [PrimaryKey] attribute to tell OrmLite to
>   use a different property for the primary key.
>
> You can still SELECT from these tables, you will just be unable to
>   make use of APIs that rely on it, e.g. Update or Delete where the
>   filter is implied (i.e. not specified), all the APIs that end with
>   ById, etc.
>
> Workaround single Primary Key limitation
>
> A potential workaround to support tables with multiple primary keys is
>   to create an auto generated Id property that returns a unique value
>   based on all the primary key fields,

So I tried to add this

```
public class PODetail {
    public string Id { get { return this.ItemCode + "/" + this.POno; } }
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }
    public string NewItemCode { get; set; }
    public string POno { get; set; }
    :
}
```

But when it went to execute :

```
Db.SingleFmt<PODetail>
```

It error out with ID not a valid column or column not found or something like that

So I then tried

```
public class PODetail {
    //public string Id { get { return this.ItemCode + "/" + this.POno; } }
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }
    public string NewItemCode { get; set; }
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string POno { get; set; }
    :
}
```

and it worked on the Db.SingleFmt ...  and the Db.Update

So then I added back in the CaptureSqlFilter to see what the query looked like and I got

```
UPDATE "PODetail" SET "NewItemCode"=@NewItemCode, "Vendor"=@Vendor, "ActionCode"=@ActionCode, "Price"=@Price, "NewPrice"=@NewPrice, "CostPrice"=@CostPrice, "QtyOrd"=@QtyOrd, "QtyRcv"=@QtyRcv, "QtySPO"=@QtySPO, "QtyPend"=@QtyPend, "BackOrder"=@BackOrder, "OpenOrder"=@OpenOrder, "OrderDate"=@OrderDate, "InvoiceNo"=@InvoiceNo, "InvoiceVendor"=@InvoiceVendor, "InvoiceDate"=@InvoiceDate, "InvoiceDiscount"=@InvoiceDiscount, "QtyCancel"=@QtyCancel, "Qtylabels"=@Qtylabels, "REOVendor"=@REOVendor, "CurrentRcvQty"=@CurrentRcvQty, "SOPickQty"=@SOPickQty, "SOItem"=@SOItem, "QtyOther"=@QtyOther, "BackOrderCode"=@BackOrderCode WHERE "ItemCode"=@ItemCode AND "POno"=@POno
```

Which is what I wanted in the first place.

It works but what is the deal can you have the [PrimaryKey] attribute multiple times (it appears so) and also then why didn't the autogenerated Id work?  Just wondering if I am missing something or not understanding the documentation correctly.

Oh and sorry for posting in the comments!

Answer (score 0):

> what I do I need to change so that it knows both PoNo and ItemCode are
>   primary Keys

[OrmLite's primary limitation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#limitations) is that each Table has a **single primary Key**.

Also you can use the [built-in Profiling](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Built-in-profiling) or [debug logging](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Logging) to view the generated SQL without needing to change code to use `CaptureSqlFilter`.

I'd also recommend that you don't use the Request DTO for [anything other than defining your Service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32940275/85785) with. You can use the [built-in AutoMapping](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-mapping) to easily use it to populate your data model.

Comment: Thanks let me look at that code to handle multiple primary keys

Comment: @MarkSummers Update question to add code, (i.e. don't post in comments). If your table doesn't have a single primary key it can't OrmLite's Update API's. You'd need to use `db.ExecuteSql()` directly.