# Handling aggregates in ServiceStack models

Tags: c#, servicestack

I'm working on a ServiceStack-based project that has an MVC web app and some messaging/polling apps that run as Azure webjobs. The project uses the general structure recommended in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231537/recommended-servicestack-api-structure), but I'm finding that some of my requirements don't fit particularly well.

Specifically, what is the recommended way to handle aggregates in models? For example, let's say I want to have a `Statistics` model that looks something like this:

```
public class Statistics
{
    public int TotalCompletedSessions { get; set; }
    public int TotalAbandonedSessions { get; set; }

    public int AverageSessionDuration { get; set; }
    public int MaxSessionDuration { get; set; }
}
```

This is a simplistic example, but would I be better off to create a `StatisticsRequest` class that would return a `StatisticsResponse` DTO, with my service interface using OrmLite to pull a query that would return the aggregates? Or should I just have the service be super-RESTful and focus on delivering only resources (in the example above, full `Session` objects) and calculate those aggregates using some sort of business logic layer?

If the latter, where should that business logic exist, and could/should it be available to external clients?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend following [a YAGNI approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32940275/85785) and always strive for the simplest solution that works with least effort, abstraction and indirection required, which in this case sounds like a single OrmLite query.

Comment: Thanks @mythz. You think it would make sense to have a dedicated request/response DTO even though an aggregate object like this isn't exactly a *resource* per se? Or am I better off just pulling a collection of the resources and doing the calculations at the client? I'm torn between true-blue REST and easy/efficient.

Comment: @Josh Always take the easy/efficient option, your Customers always benefit from better perf/responsiveness and any time you save on dev you can spend on adding value. There's little tangible benefit in wasting time/energy trying to over design it.