# Does ServiceStack JsonSerializer support ISerializable

Tags: c#, json, serialization, servicestack-text

Can `ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer` to work with class that implements `ISerializable` **instead of** taking public properties?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No `ISerializable` doesn't have any impact in ServiceStack.Text serializers which by default only serializes **public properties** but can be made to also serialize **public fields** with:

```
JsConifg.IncludePublicFields = true;
```

There are also a number of different ways to [ignore fields you don't want serialized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14859968/85785).

Comment: It's unfortunate, since ISerializable sounds as a standard interface that is worth to support.

Comment: @LeoY it's not, it's only for Microsoft Serializers and imposes an unnecessary implementation.