# How do you get ServiceStack.ToJson to *sometimes* ignore properties?

Tags: servicestack

I have a ServiceStack DTO:

```
[Route("/images", "POST")]
public class PostImageCommand
{
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    //other properties removed for brevity
}
```

I also have a part in my code that logs messages using log4net. I do this by serializing the command. For example, I just do this:

```
var command = new PostImageCommand(){
    //set properties
};

var commandJson = command.ToJson();
MyLogClass.Log(commandJson);
```

**The problem**: The Image byte array can get pretty large. I do not want to serialize this property when logging, or else my log will be filled with large amounts of image data.

I tried putting the `[IgnoreDataMember]` attribute on the Image byte[] in the DTO. However, that causes the build to fail without Visual Studio saying why. I can put the Attribute on the Image property, but when I try to build I see this:

[image]

No reason why the build failed, just these messages. The Output tab only says "The operation was canceled".

**My question**: What is the easiest way to ignore a DTO property from being serialized in my situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This previous answer lists the [different ways to ignore properties in ServiceStack.Text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14859968/85785). But really if you just want to ignore the property from being logged you can just set the property to `null` then restore it, map it to a different model with just the types you want serialized using the [built-in AutoMapping tools](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-mapping), Use `ToObjectDictionary()` extension method to serialize your model into a dictionary then remove the items you don't want logged.

The issue you're having with the `[IgnoreDataMember]` attribute is because you haven't referenced the **System.Runtime.Serialization** .NET Framework Assembly.

Comment: An answer from the main man himself, thanks! This helped me out.

Comment: @ohyeah np :) glad it helped!