# ServiceStack.Text JsonConfig Scoping Ignoring Attributes

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-text

I'm looking to effectively create logic via attributes on a .net core API project that, depending on a attribute will serialise or de-serialise while ignoring certain properties.

Eg.

If a property was decorated with **[OutputOnly]** it would not allow users to pass it in via the API, but the API would be able to return this value.

Inversely **[InputOnly]** would enable users to only pass this value in, but an API would not return this.

The issue I am having is **JsConfig** static and the property (**IgnoreAttributesNamed**) that enables Ignoring fields is a singleton too and not part of the Scope functionality in **JsConfig.With()**

My idea currently is to have an InputFormatter and an OutputFormatter in .net core, that will handle the this logic, but need to be able to config which properties are ignored in those contexts

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand what the goal is here, you would use a Request DTO to define which Parameters a Service Accepts and Response DTO to define what your Service returns, the explicit purpose of the Request/Response DTOs is to define your Services Contract, i.e. the most [important contract in your System](https://docs.servicestack.net/why-remote-services-use-dtos), whose well-defined interface is used to [encapsulate your systems capabilities](https://docs.servicestack.net/service-complexity-and-dto-roles#services) and is what all consumers of your APIs binds to.

The C# POCO used to define your Request/Response DTO classes should be considered as a DSL for defining the inputs/outputs of your API, trying to [collapse and merge their explicit intent](https://docs.servicestack.net/why-remote-services-use-dtos#dry-vs-intent) of your APIs into multi competing Types with custom attributes is self-defeating, it adds unnecessary confusion, blurs its explicit definition which invalidates the primary purpose of having service contracts which is what all metadata services look at for documenting your API and generating the typed bindings in [different supported languages](https://docs.servicestack.net/add-servicestack-reference).

So the approach and desired goal for using custom attributes for controlling serialization behavior so you can reuse the same types in different contracts is highly discouraged, but should you wish to continue with this approach you can refer to this answer for [different ways to Ignore properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14859968/85785) in ServiceStack.Text, specifically `ShouldSerailize()` API which will allow you to dynamically specify which fields ServiceStack.Text should serialize, if you intend on implementing a convention you can delegate the implementation to a custom extension method, e.g:

```
class MyRequest
{
     public bool? ShouldSerialize(string fieldName) => 
         MyUtils.ShouldSerialize(GetType(),fieldName);
}
```

Other than the linked answer the only other opportunity to manipulate serialization is potentially to use the [built-in AutoMapping utils](https://docs.servicestack.net/auto-mapping) for selecting which properties should be copied over and the [Object Dictionary APIs](https://docs.servicestack.net/reflection-utils#converting-instances-from-an-object-dictionary) for converting C# Types into an Object Dictionary and manipulate it that way, then can dehydrate it back into the C# type after applying your conventions.

Comment: I think in essence we were trying to avoid having DTO overload, by just omitting fields during the serialisation process. and we find that attributes are more readable for reading over the code vs ShouldSerialize.

Appreciate your help as always though!, was hoping there was a way to Scope the ignored attributes logic

Comment: @Mitch ok in that case I've expanded my answer to explain why merging and reusing different types for defining service contracts is discouraged.